# Visual Studio 2010 Setup Wizard will not build the solution with a 3.5 GB SqlCE database

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I am creating a package installer using Setup Wizard in Visual Studio 2010 Premium.  The solution has VB.NET classes, .dll's created in C#, Lucene.NET dll, and iTextSharp dll. The application also uses a SqlCE database which is around 3.5 GB.  I can build the package installer/Setup Wizard solution perfectly without including the SqlCE database. However, the problem: When I include the SqlCE database in the build, I get the error:

'Could not find file '.\database1.sdf' 'Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.'

I tried to solve it based on these suggestions: http://stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2008/04/29/hacking-visual-studio-to-use-more-than-2gigabytes-of-memory.aspx

However, not enough memory cannot be the issue because the package installer is built on a workstation with 20+ GB of memory and plenty of hard drive space.  I tried most of the other suggestions on the site mentioned above.

My goal is to have an installer for this program and to have it automatically install or copy the SqlCE database to the program's directory which is was installed to.  I don't care if the SqlCE database is included in the package installer... if there is a way to add a script (to the package installer) that copies the database to the program directory (during installation) than I am open to that solution as well.

Given these issues, how can I install or copy the SqlCE database to the program directory (i.e. the program is installed, how can I install the SqlCE database as well, given the issues I mentioned?).  I don't want to have the users manually copy the database over to the program directory post-installation.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Alternatively to creating an installer solution, I can use the "publish" setting in the project properties to create an installer.  I think its called a "web installer", but anyway, it accomplishes the same thing: it builds an installer which allows the application to be deployed.